# Is it possible to do multiple 301 redirects with in a php file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, vbulletin, xenforo

So I need to redirect  requests to this missing file

```
#####.php/this-is-the-name/
```

to something like this

```
/#####/######.6456436/
```

The php file no longer exists.

There are multiple URLs like this. Is it possible to add 301 redirects within that missing php file?

To clarify a bit, these are urls that were on a VBulletin forum but were coming from the cms option. Some need to be redirected to Xenforo threads and others need to be redirected to Xeenforo forums.

The url that is no loinger in existance and that IO need to redirect is this

content.php?r=262-this-is-the-private-title-S%21

It needs to go to this

/threads/new-private-title.243914/

The file. content.php was for Vbulletin but we now run Xenforo which is why this url is broken. I hope this clarifies..

Comment: Apologies but your question is a bit unclear. You won't be able to add redirects to the missing file. Are you wanting to redirect requests for the missing file to somewhere else?

Comment: You can do multiple redirects in PHP, but it would be much easier and faster to do this in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`.

Comment: You can change to any URL you want? If there is no PHP file, you should do this in htaccess.

Comment: Are the `#####` in your target URL supposed to correspond to `#####.php/`? Is the `6456436` static, or somehow dependent on the old URL?

Comment: The number is static, it corresponds to threads and there are multiple requests that need to be redirected.  These are old Vbulletin cms URLs that need to be redirected to Xenforo threads.

Comment: Still all a bit vague & imprecise. `#####.php/this-is-the-name/ ` - which part of this is the relevant one to decide this needs to be redirected? Only the script name? And would that be _one_ static script file, or does `#####` mean multiple/any? Or does the redirect happen based on the `this-is-the-name` part?

Comment: It is not a script. It is a url. The redirect needs to be based on the entire url. The #### was just to not show the name of the file but it doesn’t really matter. It’s content.pho

Comment: Maybe you catch up not found php files from 404 page and redirect to what you want to redirect you.

Comment: Now we got one specific example URL, but you said you had to redirect multiple - so what is the _pattern_? Or isn't there actually one? Because you said from `content.php?r=262-this-is-the-private-title-S%21` to `/threads/new-private-title.243914/` - but the server can't really guess that `this-is-the-private-title` should become `new-private-title` now. In that case, you won't have a choice besides creating an individual redirect for each one.